# How to highlight calendar dates which dates are come from the database

Tags: android, calendar

I am having a dates database where i am having more than one date,so I want to highlight the background of all the dates which i got from the database i tried some logic but it didn't succeed here i put my code it goes in infinite loop.i want output something like this suppose i am having dates like in database 5/3/2013 and 9/3/2013 then that two dates background should be highlight on calendar view.  i used this link http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html here is my code :

here in printmonth() function i made changes

```
public class CalendarActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private static final String tag = "CalendarActivity";
private TextView currentMonth;
private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
private ImageView prevMonth;
private ImageView nextMonth;
private GridView calendarView;
private GridCellAdapter adapter;
private Calendar _calendar;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private int month, year;

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";
int i;
String valuofday;
int stryear;
DB_Database db;
String strmonthvalueofdatabase;
String[] strdate;
String value;
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_calendar_view);
    db = new DB_Database(this);

    _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    // Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " +
    // "Year: "
    // + year);

    selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
            .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
    selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

    prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
    prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
    currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
            _calendar.getTime()));

    nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
    nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

    // Initialised
    adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param month
 * @param year
 */
private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
    adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
    _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
            _calendar.getTime()));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == prevMonth) {
        if (month <= 1) {
            month = 12;
            year--;
        } else {
            month--;
        }
        // Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
        // + month + " Year: " + year);
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
    }
    if (v == nextMonth) {
        if (month > 11) {
            month = 1;
            year++;
        } else {
            month++;
        }
        // Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
        // + month + " Year: " + year);
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
    super.onDestroy();
}

// Inner Class
public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
    private final Context _context;
    private final List<String> list;
    private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
    private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
            "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
    private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" };
    private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
            31, 30, 31 };
    private int daysInMonth;
    private int currentDayOfMonth;
    private int currentWeekDay;
    private Button gridcell;
    private TextView num_events_per_day;
    private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd-MMM-yyyy");

    // Days in Current Month
    public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            int month, int year) {
        super();
        this._context = context;
        this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
        // + "Year: " + year);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        stryear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        // Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
        // Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
        // Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
        printMonth(month, year);

        eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
    }

    private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
        return months[i];
    }

    private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
        return weekdays[i];
    }

    private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
        return daysOfMonth[i];
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    /**
     * Prints Month
     * 
     * @param mm
     * @param yy
     */
    private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
        // Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
        // The number of days to leave blank at
        // the start of this month.

        int trailingSpaces = 0;
        int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
        int prevMonth = 0;
        int prevYear = 0;
        int nextMonth = 0;
        int nextYear = 0;

        int currentMonth = mm - 1;
        String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
        daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

        // Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName +
        // " having "
        // + daysInMonth + " days.");

        // Gregorian Calendar : MINUS 1, set to FIRST OF MONTH
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
        // Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

        if (currentMonth == 11) {
            prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            nextMonth = 0;
            prevYear = yy;
            nextYear = yy + 1;
            // Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
            // + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
            // + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
        } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
            prevMonth = 11;
            prevYear = yy - 1;
            nextYear = yy;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            nextMonth = 1;
            // Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
            // + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
            // + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
        } else {
            prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
            nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
            nextYear = yy;
            prevYear = yy;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            // Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
            // + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
            // + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
        }

        // Compute how much to leave before before the first day of the
        // month.
        // getDay() returns 0 for Sunday.
        int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
        String strcurrentweekdat = Integer.toString(currentWeekDay);
        Log.v("currentweekdays", strcurrentweekdat);
        trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

        // Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
        // + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
        // Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
        // Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

        if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && mm == 1) {
            ++daysInMonth;
        }

        // Trailing Month days
        for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
            // Log.d(tag,
            // "PREV MONTH:= "
            // + prevMonth
            // + " => "
            // + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
            // + " "
            // + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
            // - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
            // + i));
            list.add(String
                    .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                            + i)
                    + "-GREY"
                    + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                    + "-"
                    + prevYear);

        }
        String strcurrentmonth = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
        Log.v("strcurrentmonth", strcurrentmonth);

        String strcurrentyear = Integer.toString(stryear);
        Log.v("strcurrentmonth", strcurrentyear);

        // for database file

        SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlitedatabase.query(DB_Database.REPORT, null,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        int hilihgtedDate = 0;

        // get array of hilighted dates...
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

        // get array of hilighted dates...
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            arraylist.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DB_Database.REPORT_MEDICINE_DATE)));
            hilihgtedDate++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext() == true);

        // now that you have the dates to be hilighted, create the month
        // view as you were doing previously,
        // Trailing Month days
        for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
            Log.d(tag,
                    "PREV MONTH:= "
                            + prevMonth
                            + " => "
                            + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                            + " "
                            + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
                                    - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                    + i));
            list.add(String
                    .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                            + i)
                    + "-GREY"
                    + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                    + "-"
                    + prevYear);
        }

        int k = 0;
        // Current Month Days
        for (i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {

            // prevents un-ncesessart splitting steps...
            if (k <= hilihgtedDate) {
                /*
                 * checks if current date is equal to 1st hilighted date...
                 * if yes, then hilight the date and get the next hilihgted
                 * date, if no, then just add that date
                 */
                Log.v("string arraylist", arraylist.get(i));
                String[] splitstrdate = arraylist.get(k).split("/");

                String splitstrday = splitstrdate[0];
                Log.v("splitstrday", splitstrday);
                int intsplitstrday = Integer.parseInt(splitstrday);

                String splitstrmonth = splitstrdate[1];
                int intmonth = Integer.parseInt(splitstrmonth);

                int newintvalue = intmonth - 1;
                String splitstryear = splitstrdate[2];
                int intsplitstryear = Integer.parseInt(splitstryear);
                for (i = 0; i < newintvalue; i++) {
                    String strone = Integer.toString(newintvalue);
                    strone = months[i];
                    Log.v("strone", strone);
                }
                Log.v("month value", months[i].toString());
                String strentermonth = months[i].toString();

                if (i == intsplitstrday && strcurrentmonth == strentermonth
                        && year == intsplitstryear) {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    k++;
                } else {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                }
            } else {
                /*
                 * There are no more hilighted dates, so no need to split
                 * the date and do the checking, simply write the dates as
                 * they are...
                 */
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
            }
        }

        // Leading Month days
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
            Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
            list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
        }

    }

    /**
     * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
     * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
     * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
     * day.
     * 
     * @param year
     * @param month
     * @return
     */

    private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
            int month) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, false);
        }

        // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
        gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
        gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);
        // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

        // Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
        String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
        Log.v("string value", day_color[1]);
        // Log.v("day",valuofday);

        String theday = day_color[0];
        String themonth = day_color[2];
        String theyear = day_color[3];

        if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
            if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
            }
        }
        // Set the Day GridCell
        gridcell.setText(theday);

        gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);

        // Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
        // + theyear);
        Log.v("str daycolor", day_color[1]);

        if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
            gridcell.setTextColor(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.lightgray));
        }
        if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
            gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.lightgray02));
        }
        if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
            gridcell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.orrange));
        }
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
        // Log.e("Selected date", date_month_year);
        try {
            Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
            // Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
        return currentDayOfMonth;
    }

    private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
        this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
    }

    public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
        this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
    }

    public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
        return currentWeekDay;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you have re-initiated value of variable `i`. It should look something like this:

```
int j = 0;
for (; j < newintvalue; j++) {
    String strone = Integer.toString(newintvalue);
    strone = months[j];
    Log.v("strone", strone);
}
Log.v("month value", months[j].toString());
String strentermonth = months[j].toString();
```